# Interface usage and polymorphic coding

Tags: java

I have a few classes. I would like to point out this:
`BaseDAO` class that implements `Queryable` and `Parcelable` interfaces. 
There are a few subclasses of Base one and I would like to call method

```
public static ResultSet getDataFor(Queryable queryable) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    return statement.executeQuery(queryable.getSelectAllQuery());
}
```

universally, two lines for all subs of Base.

But right now the call looks ugly like `getDataFor(new Program())` or with a different class.

So basically, my question is is there a better way to implement this behaviour without calling with a new instance.
I wanted to keep this as laconic as possible so feel free to ask questions

Comment: Why do you need to pass `new Program()` without any particular attributes, anything in the constructor and no setter calls?

Comment: @JoseDaSilva every subclass of `BaseDAO` has its own String field `SELECT_ALL` holding a query. So in order to determine what query to use I pass an empty object into the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the class I can think in three solutions.

---

**Use an enum**

If you want/need more control of the types it will receive:

```java
enum BaseType {
    PROGRAM(new Program()),
    ANOTHER(new Another());
    private BaseDAO baseDAO;
    BaseType (BaseDAO baseDAO) {
        this.baseDAO = baseDAO;
    }
    public BaseDAO getBaseDAO() {
        return baseDAO;
    }
}

public static ResultSet getDataFor(BaseType type) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    return statement.executeQuery(type.getBaseDAO().getSelectAllQuery());
}
```

With static import

```java
import static my.pack.BaseType;

getDataFor(PROGRAM);
```

Without static import

```java
getDataFor(BaseType.PROGRAM);
```

---

**Use Reflection**

If you don't want/need more control of the types it will receive:

```java
public static ResultSet getDataFor(Class<? extends BaseDao> type) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    return statement.executeQuery(type.newInstance()
        .getSelectAllQuery()); // handle exceptions
}
```

Use it like

```java
getDataFor(Program.class);
```

---

**Use a supplier**

Also if you don't want/need more control of the types it will receive:

```java
public static ResultSet getDataFor(Supplier<? extends BaseDao> supplier) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    return statement.executeQuery(supplier.get().getSelectAllQuery());
}
```

Use it like

```java
getDataFor(Program::new); // looks good, at least to me
```

---

You cannot use generics for this because of the type erasure. If java had reified generics you could use something like `getDataFor<Program>()`, but it cannot be done.

Comment: I've been thinking about something like 2nd solution but was unable to write code like this. Thanks! Consider the question to be closed for now

Comment: but what do you mean when you say "more control of the types"?

Comment: Well in the enum you need to tell exactly the types you would receive, e.g. Program, MyDao1, MyDao2... You know exactly what you could receive and if want to receive something else you have to add it to the enum. With supplier or reflection you don't, you could receive any subclass of BaseDao without adding it to any place.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. 
As I can see supplier and reflection methods are almost the same with minor differences. Which one would you recommend to use and what are the pros/cons if any?

Comment: I personally tend more to Reflection methods because I've been thinking about a way to pass Program.class as an argument but didn't know a way to do that.

Comment: Reflection is always slower, also if you pass for instance BaseDao.class (I asume BaseDao abstract or interface), the code will compile just fine, but it will throw a runtime exception. Supplier by the other hand just need an empty constructor or a factory method without arguments.

Comment: But I think is just preference, since the performance hit normally is litle, you have to be a little more careful in the code though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166646/discussion-between-volkeee-and-jose-da-silva).

Answer (score 1):

Make `getDataFor`() an instance method of `BaseDAO`. In that way, it will have access to the seudo-argument `this`, that will point to the instance on which you'll execute the method.

Comment: The problem is that I have 5 subclasses of `BaseDAO` class so in this way I will have to write 5 exactly identical methods and I don't want to do that.

Comment: good idea, kind sir!
But there is a slight problem. It mixes "theme" of the class. the `getDataFor` is in `SQLHelper` class that is for querying and stuff. And holding this method would mix things up a bit